# Is HighCharts supported in IE9?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, highcharts

Is Highcharts supported in IE9?

As I tried to add a button that changes it’s fill – while it works perfect on Mozila Firefox, it doesn't seem to be working at all in IE9.

Comment: Here is jFiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AvpDk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts is supported from IE6+ according to the [official documentation.](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility)

[image]

Although note that as it mentions in the documentation, performance in IE8 and before isn't that great in comparrison to IE9 and other browsers such as Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: still although their claim to be supported - it's not working for 
me :(

Comment: performance is not the issue - the button is not filled with Red color.

Comment: Chrome no, Safari I haven't tested it.
Also I found that it shows an error in Chrom console

Comment: @ChananBerler Chrome is the most popular browser, so it must be a problem in-code, if you sort it out for chrome it might work in IE too.

Comment: Error found in Chrome:
Error: Problem parsing d="M 175 212.5 A 1.83e-322 1.83e-322 0 1 1 175 212.5 M 174.99988449999995 97.00000000005777 A 115.49999999999999 115.49999999999999 0 1 0 175 97.00000000000001 " 

Line: 245

Comment: @ChananBerler, I tried your linked fiddle, in Chrome, when I mouseover the button fill turns red.  In IE, when I mouseover the button fill does not change.  Otherwise the button renders and works in both.  Is that the problem?  I'm using Chrome 25 and IE9.